# Magento Block Not Displaying

Tags: magento, controller, block

For Some reason i cant get this contoller to display. Please what am i doing wrong here? The controller works fine but for some reason i cant get the block to display using this method.

```
Here is the indexController, which is basically adding the layout and rendering it out too. The indexController is located in the module controller folder.
    IndexController.php


    <?php

            class MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
        {
            public function indexAction()
            {
                $this->loadLayout();
                return $this->renderLayout();
            }
        }

Here is the Welcome block which is located in the  MasteringMagento/ChapterBlockTemplate/Block/Welcome

    Welcome.php

        class MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Block_Welcome extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
        {
            public function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->setTemplate('chapterblocktemplate/welcome.phtml');
            }
        }

This is the config file which is located in the etc folder. I have just posted a full config.xml file. I cant seem to see anything wrong with the code.    
    config.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate>
                <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate_resource</resourceModel>
            </masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate>
            <masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate_resource>
                <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Model_Resource</class>
            </masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate_resource>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate>
                <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Block</class>
            </masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate>
                <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Helper</class>
            </masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate>
        </helpers>
    </global>

Here is the frontend route which is part of the config file
    <frontend>

        <routers>
            <chapterblocktemplate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>chapterblocktemplate</frontName>
                    <module>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate</module>
                </args>
            </chapterblocktemplate>
        </routers>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <chapterblocktemplate>
                    <file>chapterblocktemplate.xml</file>
                </chapterblocktemplate>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>


Here is the layout file, which is located in magento default layout folder  
    chapterblocktemplate.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <layout version="0.1.0">

        <chapterblocktemplate_index_index>

            <update handle="page_two_columns_right"/>

            <reference name="content">

                <!--Second way to load a template-->
                <block type="chapterblocktemplate/welcome"/>
            </reference>


        </chapterblocktemplate_index_index>

    </layout>
i also created a template folder name chapterblocktemplate and i have a file named welcome.phtml in it.
```

I have updated the whole code again, Still no luck. What am i missing? This is kind of Strange.
    Thanks

Comment: You have missed the router configuration in config.xml

Comment: As you written "This is the config file which is located in the controllers folder.". Do you have place the config.xml in controller folder or etc folder ? Also check that you have added module activation file

Comment: My mistake, the config file is inside the etc   folder. The module was also created with Magicento..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to create module configuration file under app/etc/MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate.xml

Please make sure with this.

Comment: I have the this in my config file :<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate>
    </modules>
</config>

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your layout

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <chapterblocktemplate>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate</module>
                <frontName>chapterblocktemplate</frontName>
            </args>
        </chapterblocktemplate>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <chapterblocktemplate>
                <file>chapterblocktemplate.xml</file>
            </chapterblocktemplate>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Comment: i already have it:         <routers>
            <chapterblocktemplate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>chapterblocktemplate</frontName>
                    <module>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate</module>
                </args>
            </chapterblocktemplate>
        </routers>

Answer (score 0):

Add Frontend Router Configuration in `<frontend>` tag in `config.xml`

```
    <routers>
        <chapterblocktemplate>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate</module>
                <frontName>chapterblocktemplate</frontName>
            </args>
        </chapterblocktemplate>
    </routers>
```

Comment: I already have something similar :         <routers>
            <chapterblocktemplate>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>chapterblocktemplate</frontName>
                    <module>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate</module>
                </args>
            </chapterblocktemplate>
        </routers>

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. just wanted to thank each and everyone of you for his/her contributions.

The problem was on the etc/config.xml

I replaced the global section with the code below, Instead of having both the namespace_modulename (masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate) you should only have the module name (chapterblocktemplate).

```
<global>
    <models>
        <chapterblocktemplate>
            <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>masteringmagento_chapterblocktemplate_resource</resourceModel>
        </chapterblocktemplate>
        <chapterblocktemplate_resource>
            <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Model_Resource</class>
        </chapterblocktemplate_resource>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <chapterblocktemplate>
            <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Block</class>
        </chapterblocktemplate>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <chapterblocktemplate>
            <class>MasteringMagento_ChapterBlockTemplate_Helper</class>
        </chapterblocktemplate>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Hope it helps someone else :)
Enjoy